# JRadioButton and ButtonGroup errors

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I am trying to use JRadioButtons and ButtonGroup in my project.I am using Eclipse IDE and when I am adding JRadioButtons to the ButtonGroup it is showing error.
[image]

on moving arrow on these these red crosses it is showing multiple markers at this line

Comment: We can't copy-paste an image, if you really want help then copy-paste your code here, preferably an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to put a little more code, but as I guess from the picture, you are trying to set attributes to the *initialized fields* **outside of any method or constructor**, which gives a compiler error. Move the setting of attributes inside the constructor or any method and your errors will be resolved.

Comment: @Yastika Kumar: So did the answer help you to solve errors?